# Cannot access div which is created by ajax (is dynamic)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, electron

I'm developing an app using Electron and I want to make different pages. I created an index.html, and another one: seeds.html. (I will be adding more and this one is just for test)
What I do is to load the content of the selected page (ex. addseed.html) via jQuery `.load()` inside a div with "main" class in index.html.
Now the problem is after I load `addseed`, the table doesn't show older queries. I tested and it can read the file correctly, but the main problem is appending them to the dynamically created table. However, after I add a new item, it shows correctly, but older items don't.

(there are "contact"s instead of "seed"s cause I'm going through a tutorial and code is just for test :D )

```
function addEntry(seed, price, image) {
    if(seed && price && image) {
        sno++
        let updateString = '<tr> <td>' + sno + '</td> <td>'+ seed +'</td> <td>' + price +'</td> <td> <img  width="200px" height="200px" src="' + image + '"> </td> </tr>' 
        $('#contact-table').append(updateString)
    }
}
function loadAndDisplayContacts() {  
   $("#status").text("function works\n")
   //Check if file exists
   if(fs.existsSync('contacts.txt')) {
       let data = fs.readFileSync('contacts.txt', 'utf8').split('\n')

       data.forEach((contact, index) => {
           let [ seed, price, image ] = contact.split(',')
          addEntry(seed, price, image)
       })
   } else {
       console.log("File Doesn\'t Exist. Creating new file.")
       fs.writeFile('contacts.txt', '', (err) => {
           if(err)
               console.log(err)
       })
   }
}

$(document).on('click', '#addseed', () => {      
    $(".main").load("addseed.html")
    loadAndDisplayContacts()
})
```

and this the html for 'addseed.html':

```
<div class="container main">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Seed">Seed</label>
    <input type="text" Seed="Seed" value="" id="Seed" placeholder="Seed" class="form-control" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Price">Price</label>
    <input type="Price" Seed="Price" value="" id="Price" 
       placeholder="Price" class="form-control" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Image">Image</label>
    <input type="Image" Seed="Image" value="" id="Image" 
       placeholder="Image" class="form-control" required>
</div>

<button id="openFile" onclick="openFile();">Open</button>

<p>this is filepath: <span id="filee"></span></p>

<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add to list!</button>
</div>

<div id="contact-list">
    <table class="table-striped" id="contact-table">
        <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-2">S. No.</th>
            <th class="col-xs-4">Seed</th>
            <th class="col-xs-6">Price</th>
            <th class="col-xs-8">Image</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

and in `index.html` I have:

```
    <button id="addseed">Add</button>
    <div class="main"></div> <!--the content should be added here as a child of main-->
    <p id="status"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not waiting for the asynchronous AJAX to complete. You need to call the function that depends on the updated DOM as a callback function.

```
$(document).on('click', '#addseed', () => {      
    $(".main").load("addseed.html", loadAndDisplayContacts)
})
```

And in `addseed.html`, change `class="container main"` to just `class="container"`. You're loading the file into the `main` DIV in `index.html`, it doesn't replace the DIV. So you're creating two DIVs with that class, and the next click loads the file into both of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there's another problem: when I change the page and come back, the whole table is duplicated.

Comment: You have `class="main"` in `index.html`, and also in `addseed.html`. The next time you click, it loads the content into both of them, so you get a duplicate.

Comment: So should I remove (empty) the table each time or it is better to prevent adding duplicate rows?

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain what you need to do.